# Get notification to the currently logged users

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services

I want to add a notifications to my asp.net application. when place an order to order table,automatically popup should come to the currently logged users such as facebook notification. 
please help with sample codes 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx) to achieve this.

To enable this option in your database you have to enable  `Service Broker` which is not enable by default. Have a look  how to [Enabling Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172133%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Also have a look how you can use [SqlNotificationRequest and Detecting Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ht3391b.aspx)